# DateTime conversion is not working while reading dates from excel where Day > 12

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus, asp.net-4.5

This is my first 5 rows in my XLSX file:

[image]

Note that the format for the `ResLastCallDate` column is `CustomFormat->dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`. Yet, Row 4 looks different than the others for some reason. This is not important a lot tho, the important part is that the XLSX file is being uploaded to my asp.net 4.5 web page where I read the data via EPPlus. However, when I am reading ResLastCallDate column, I am receiving an error. See the code below:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(dr["ResLastCallDate"].ToString(),provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out resLastCallDate))
{
     Msg = Msg + string.Format("Row {0}: ResLastCallDate is not date ({1}).\n", r, dr["ResLastCallDate"].ToString());
}
...
txtDebug.Text = Msg;
```

I have tried not to use a provider, other DateTimeStyles, none of them worked, except Row 4 in the excel always been read correctly. See the output:

```
Row 0: ResLastCallDate is not date (20/03/2018 13:58)
Row 1: ResLastCallDate is not date (20/03/2018 13:58)
Row 3: ResLastCallDate is not date (15/03/2018 20:25)
```

So Row 2 (which equals ClientID=3621) works but others not for a reason. I've tried General and Date formats in the excel for those cells, still not working. What else I can do to handle this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: When I convert it to dr["ResLastCallDate"].ToString() only (no provider I use), it works on my local machine, but when I publish to the server it does not work (same error message received)

Comment: I personally have never had a chance to parse DateTime but how about using DateTime.ParseExact method? it seems that you can specify the format of the input.

Comment: @mjwills the data with PM works well. but PM is not related, changing the Times (with or without AM/PM) does not make difference for others.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] and a xlsx file that repros the issue, so we can run it on our end.

Comment: @Gnbrkm41 same error.

Comment: Could you tell me what the system local culture is, as well? I'm assuming en-GB, but just to confirm.

Comment: @Gnbrkm41 en-gb. Other DateTimeStyles also I've tried, no luck.

Comment: Just wondering, how does the parsed DateTime look like at row 3?

Comment: @Gnbrkm41 when System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal (Same as DateTimeStyles.None) used as datetimestyle, It is: 2018-06-04 6:07:00 PM  (others are not working)

Comment: You say _Yet, Row 4 looks different than the others for some reason. This is not important a lot tho_.  Well, it probably _is_ important: rows 2, 3, 5 are Strings, that just happen to look like dates (if you assume dd/mm/yyyy).  Row 4 is a date, and I it might actually be 4th June, not 6th April, depending on your locale (not the custom date format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that CultureInfo.InvariantCulture does not like to receive strings in that particular format. I believe it's related to the fact that in the US date is written in MM/dd/yyyy order whereas in Europe it is written in dd/MM/yyyy (which includes the UK, and Australia).

If that's the case, `20/03/2010 13:58` would have been parsed as 3rd day of 20th month, 2010, which does not make any sense.

I believe using `new CultureInfo("en-gb") instead of CultureInfo.InvariantCulture would be better choice here.

Comment: or alternatively, save the datetime accordingly to [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). :)

Answer (score 1):

Please use an appropriate culture.

```
var originalDate = "6/4/18 6:07 PM";
DateTime parsedDate;

var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-AU");
var styles = System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(originalDate, culture, styles, out parsedDate))
{
       Console.WriteLine(parsedDate);
}

        Console.WriteLine($"Parse successfull: {parsedDate}");
```

Comment: I tested with your date use cases and it did parse well.

Comment: Please post answers and not questions.

Comment: Parse successfull: 20/03/2018 12:00:00 AM

This is what was consoled.

Comment: Thank you, actually your answer is correct as well. Just I couldn't find appropriate culture, my bad, creator of excel is not following en-US apparently. THanks!

Comment: @ErayBalkanli Excel did nothing wrong there, the way date/time is represented in text differs by regions (MM-dd-yyyy in US, dd-MM-yyyy in EU, yyyy-MM-dd in some places). Excel formatted the given datetime according to the user's PC locale, which in your case was UK's MM-dd-yyyy format. That's why there is a [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) regarding date/time formatting.